# Unit Test to make sure a function calls through to an api and assigns the data to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am working on writing and JS unit test. This is something that I still struggle with and am learning how to do properly. I have a function that calls through to an api and then assigns the data from the promise to a variable. Below is the code:

**API**

```
this.get_history = function(item_id) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('/api/items/' + item_id + '/bids', {
    ignoreLoadingBar: true
  })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.reject(data);
  });
 return deferred.promise;
};
```

**Function that calls API**

```
item.refresh_bid_history = function() {
  var self = this;
  my_api.get_history(self.id).then(function(data){self.bid_history = data});
};
```

I am trying to write a test that either makes sure the api gets called, and/or that the data part actually gets assigned to the `item.bid_history` attribute. Below is the test that I have now.

**Test**

```
it ('refresh_bid_history calls get_history API', inject(function () {
  var item_json = mock_item_details_json();
  var item = ItemService.get_item(fb_ref, item_json);
  item.bid_history = [];
  item.refresh_bid_history();
  expect(item.bid_history.length).toEqual(1);
  expect(item.bid_history[0].placed_at._d).toBeDefined();
}));
```

If you need more info I can try and provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your API return a Promise, your `expect` should not work, because when `expect` is executed, your `item.bid_history` isn't updated.

You can test directly your API `get_history`, using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/). The newest version have a native support for testing Promise, see this article: [Mocha With Promises](http://tobyho.com/2015/12/16/mocha-with-promises/).

Or if you wish to test your service, here is my [test example](https://github.com/xie-qianyue/express-angular-starter/blob/master/public/scripts/unit_test/testService.js) of todoMVC. Maybe you can get some ideas from it.

To make it simple:

1. Use `$httpBackend` to mock the back end;
2. Run your service;
3. Verify the result.

Comment: Thank you! After researching how to use ```$httpBackend``` I got it to work. I appreciate the advice.